# Swagger doesn't add new api controllers to rest (Spring boot)

Tags: spring-boot, swagger-2.0, springfox

Swagger doesn't recognize a new interface of rest api.

This are swagger configuration file.

```
package trn06.administracion.api.configuration;


import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import springfox.documentation.builders.ApiInfoBuilder;
import springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.service.ApiInfo;
import springfox.documentation.service.Contact;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;

@Slf4j
@EnableSwagger2
@Configuration
public class TRN06SwaggerConfiguration {

    @Value("${custom.host}")
    private String hostValue;

    private ApiInfo _apiInfo(final String version) {
        return new ApiInfoBuilder()
                .title("Administrative events")
                .termsOfServiceUrl("")
                .version(version)
                .contact(new Contact("",
                                     "",
                                     ""))
                .build();
    }

    private Docket _configureVersion(final String version) {

        // Get environment from java environment variables

        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .host(hostValue)
                .groupName("Version_" + version)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("trn06.administracion.api.controller.rest"))
                .paths(PathSelectors.ant("/v" + version + "/**"))
                .build()
                .useDefaultResponseMessages(false)
                .apiInfo(_apiInfo(version));
    }

    @Bean
    Docket configureV1_0() {
        return _configureVersion("1.0");
    }

}
```

All interfaces defined on package trn06.administracion.api.controller.rest are ok, in fact I have two other interfaces mapped ok, except this one:

```
package trn06.administracion.api.controller.rest;

import io.swagger.annotations.*;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import trn06.administracion.api.model.dto.TRN06ErrorDto;
import trn06.administracion.api.model.dto.TRN06EventsAuthorityDto;
import trn06.administracion.api.model.dto.TRN06ValidationErrorDto;
import java.util.List;


@Api(value = "authorities", description = "Event's authorities ", tags = "Authorities")
public interface TRN06EventsAuthorityApiController {

    @ApiOperation(value = "List of authorities", nickname = "findAuthorities", response = TRN06EventsAuthorityDto.class, responseContainer = "List", tags = {"Authorities,"})
    @ApiResponses(value = {
            @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Operation performed", response = TRN06EventsAuthorityDto.class, responseContainer = "List"),
            @ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "Validation error", response = TRN06ValidationErrorDto.class),
            @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "Not found"),
            @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Error", response = TRN06ErrorDto.class)})
    @GetMapping(value = "/v1.0/authorities",
                produces = "application/json")
    List<TRN06EventsAuthorityDto> findAuthorities();

}
```

Looks like database entity it's ok, I try making an error and was detected correctly. Try changing RequestHandlerSelectors to any(), same results.

No idea and no clue of whats appening.

Kind regards

Comment: what is the package for impacted class? is it follwing base package in swagger config?

Comment: That's right, its trn06.administracion.api.controller.rest, edited to show it right

Comment: I can see you are using interface driven controller, can you try adding **@RequesMapping** on interface. Or put the swagger annotations in actual implementation class where you have **@RestController.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an implementation of this interface and add **@RestController** and **@RequestMapping** annotations in the implementation.

For example:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/findAuthorities")
public class TRN06EventsAuthorityApiControllerImpl implements TRN06EventsAuthorityApiController {

    @Override
    public List<String> findAuthorities() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: In my case, I forgot '@RestController' annotation, but '@RequestMaping' could be helpful to map things outside the right package

Answer (score 1):

In my case, was an annotation I forgot

```
public class TRN06EventsTypesApiControllerImpl
        implements TRN06EventsTypesApiController {
....
```

After put anotation @RestController was fine

```
@RestController
public class TRN06EventsTypesApiControllerImpl
        implements TRN06EventsTypesApiController {
....
```

Anyway, I take the note of @RequestMapping annotation.

Thanks @v-mokrecov and @mahesh-loya